# How to Chop correctly?

Tags: machine-precision

I want to count degeneracies in a list called `spectrum`. The list contains numbers of double (~ 15digits) precision. So it makes no sense if the noise below this precision is taken into account since it falsifies the result of degeneracy counting using `Tally[]`. So I applied `SetPrecision`.

```
degList = Tally[{#1, SetPrecision[#2, 15]} & @@@ spectrum];
```

But I still get  e.g.
{-0.047063080371693544`, 4}
{-0.047063080371693294`, 4}
(last number is the degeneracy level)
which should be seen as equal numbers but are counted by `Tally[]` as different ones.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about something like `omegaij=Chop[Differences[spectrum], tol]` and then tallying that?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But what is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: I'll add an answer to this comment in my answer because it's a bit long for here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the second argument of `Tally`, thus:

```
Tally[{.00123, .00154}, Abs[#1 - #2] < .01 &]
(*{{0.00123, 2}}*)
```

Alternatively, look at energy level differences, `omegaij=Chop[Differences[spectrum], tol]`, then `Tally[omegaij]`.

Reply to comment (on what's wrong with the attempt in the question):

First, `SetPrecision` doesn't chop off digits; it instead sets the precision, see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html)).

Second, I am not sure what you intended `{#1, SetPrecision[#2, 15]} & @@@ spectrum` to do, but `g@@@l` just replaces the heads of everything at level 1 of `l` by `g`, for example,

```
g @@@ {a[2], b[c[d]], {{c}}}
{g[2], g[c[d]], g[{c}]}
```

If you try `g[#1, #2] & @@@ {a, b, c}` then nothing happens because the objects at level 1 are atomic (ie for the same reason that `g @@ 3` evaluates to 3). If instead you try it on something with non-atomic objects at level 1, then it bombs:

```
g[#1, #2] & @@@ {a[2], b, c}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maybe you're looking for `Map`,

```
g /@ {1, 2, 3}
(*{g[1], g[2], g[3]}*)
```

But I am probably missing something; what did you intend this to do?